# PostgreSQL 9.1.3 Database hangs when the application tries to make insertion in table

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL 9.1.3 Database hangs when the application tries to make insertion in  EventLogEntry table.

1.Schema of the table is

```
   Column    |         Type          | Modifiers
-------------+-----------------------+-----------
 tableindex  | integer               |
 object      | character varying(80) |
 method      | character varying(80) |
 bgwuser     | character varying(80) |
 time        | character(23)         |
 realuser    | character varying(80) |
 host        | character varying(80) |
 application | character varying(80) |
```

Indexes:

```
"ind1_eventlogentry" UNIQUE, btree (tableindex), tablespace "mmindex"
```

Tablespace: "mmdata"

2.On the  database which we have taken from customer site  when we were running the following query , query is hung.

```
INSERT INTO eventLogEntry (object, method, bgwUser, time, realUser, host, application, tableIndex) 
VALUES (E'Server', E'Start', E'bgw', E'20140512122404', NULL, NULL, NULL, 539  );
```

3.But when we used index after 586 like, then the insert is happening correctly on the same database.

```
INSERT INTO eventLogEntry (object, method, bgwUser, time, realUser, host, application, tableIndex  ) 
VALUES (E'Server', E'Start', E'bgw', E'20140512122404', NULL, NULL, NULL, 587 );
```

4.When we did debugging , then we found that PostgreSQL has stored some other transaction id and it asks for the current transaction to wait till the time previous transaction Either gets committed or rolled back. But we are not sure how and where PostgreSQL has stored the transaction id inside ?

5 It seems that somehow the indexes are corrupted and postgreSQL has stored some transaction id somewhere, and so it is not allowing the current transaction to happen For that particular index range.

6.When the index has been dropped and table has been recreated then everything works fine.

Plz help me with this issue by providing answers to the following queries

1. why postgreSQL is not allowing the insertion to happen for a particular index range and allowing it after that particular range?
2. where does the postgreSQL stores the transaction ids and why it is not getting refreshed ?

Comment: If two transactions insert the **same** value for a *unique* index, the second one will wait until the first commits (or rolls back).

Comment: Check `pg_locks`. Also, 9.1.3? Why aren't you on the latest patch release?